# SynPS/2 Synaptic Touchpad not working in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, xorg, touchpad, 17.10, synaptics

I have just upgraded from ubuntu 16.04 to ubuntu 17.10. My touchpad was working on ubuntu 16.04 and also on live usb of 17.10. But, it is not working after installation. My laptop is Dell inspiron 3521

Here the things I did so far:

**1) Install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics**

Touchpad worked after reboot but stopped working until now after another reboot

**2) Upgraded kernel to 4.14.0-041400-generic from 4.13**

**3) Tried copying /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d**

**4) Tried commenting out below lines in 40-libinput.conf**

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
EndSection
```

**5) Removing  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics**

Nothing worked so far

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in terminal:

> sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

You will find a line like this:

**GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"**

Now replace "quiet splash" with "acpi=force"

So the new line will be:

**GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=force"**

Save the file.

Now run this command:

> sudo update-grub

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but this didn't solve my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

This question came up for me in a Google search, so I'm posting an answer for other people who may have a similar problem.

This happened to me when dual-booting *Ubuntu 20.04* with *Windows 10*. The touchpad stopped working in Ubuntu and also in Bios, but switching to Windows and shutting it down gracefully fixed this.

It might be possible that Windows somehow blocked the device when I shut it down forcefully.

Comment: As usual, the problem is the Windows Fast Startup feature which is generally recommend to be disabled and disabling it is a must when dual-booting. It isn't Windows itself to blame here.